# Probability of yellow and white cabs given other situations

Tags: probability, statistics

In some city, 20% of the cabs are white and the other 80% are yellow. A cab was involved in an accident and ran away. An eyewitness to the accident claims that the cab was yellow. We know that the eyewitness tell the truth in 75% of the cases (and lies on the other 25%). What is the probability that the cab was indeed yellow?

What I have tried:

P(yellow) / [P(yellow) + P(white, but reported yellow)]

0.8 / [0.8 + 0.2(1 - 0.75)] = 0.94

I am unsure if I used the correct thought process for this question.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Bayes' methods to find the probability that the cab involved in the accident was actually Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66263/use-bayes-methods-to-find-the-probability-that-the-cab-involved-in-the-accident) It's the same question for different colors of cabs and visible in the column here.

Comment: You want $\dfrac{P(\text{yellow and reported yellow})}{P(\text{yellow and reported yellow}) +P(\text{white but reported yellow})}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume there are $100$ accidents.  In $20$ of those accidents, the cab was white.  In $5$ of those $20$ "white" accidents, the cab will be reported yellow.

In the other $80$ accidents, the cab was yellow.  But it will only be reported yellow in $60$ of those $80$ accidents.

We know only that the cab was reported yellow.  As discussed above, in $60$ of those $65$ reports, the cab was indeed yellow.  Thus, the correct answer is $\frac{60}{65}=\frac{12}{13}$.  Your answer is not correct because not all of the yellow accidents will actually be reported as yellow.  In other words, instead of the $0.8$ *a priori* probability that the cab was actually yellow, you should be using the smaller $0.6$ probability that the cab was correctly reported to be yellow.

Comment: Correct and well explained - but why answer a duplicate question?

Comment: @EthanBolker Because it wasn't flagged as a duplicate when I answered it, and because I believe the concrete nature of my explanation is absent from prior discussions and a useful contribution to the discussion.